# AWS Deploy my NodeJS express app

Tags: node.js, express, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

The following is my `./server.js` my angular dist is at `./client/dist` when I `node server.js` in the terminal my angular app and nodejs backend works as expected. Now how do I deploy on aws beanstalk (im open to changing beanstalk)?

Most tutorials want me to start the job from scratch but i really need the server to work as shown below like it does on localhost.

```
const express = require('express');
const colors = require('colors');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const compression = require('compression');
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');
const cors = require('cors');


// init "app"
const app = express();
var staticRoot = __dirname + '/client/dist/';
app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 5000));

app.use(cors({origin: `http://localhost:4200`}));

//parse incoming data before routes
app.use(bodyParser.json()); // for parsing application/json
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); // for parsing application/x-www-form-urlencoded

// api routes
app.use('/api',require('./api/api'));


app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    //if the request is not html then move along
    var accept = req.accepts('html', 'json', 'xml');
    if (accept !== 'html') {
        return next();
    }
    // if the request has a '.' assume that it's for a file, move along
    var ext = path.extname(req.path);
    if (ext !== '') {
        return next();
    }
    fs.createReadStream(staticRoot + 'index.html').pipe(res);
});



app.use(express.static(staticRoot));

app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
    console.log('app running on port', app.get('port'));
});
```

Comment: I am not going to minus one; but, comment instead. What has this question to do with angular...

Comment: people who have angular apps may know how to deploy them with a node backend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a modern MEAN Stack guide with full tutorials and source code.  For your question in particular, I created a step-by-step guide on how to deploy a MEAN stack app to AWS Elastic Beanstalk (https://www.meankit.io/guides/deploy-with-aws)

There's also reference links as well if you need further information.

Comment: I think this will work.. Im not certain of YARN though. Im not using it now. `ng build` will make the angular dist but im not sure how to make the `server-dist`

Comment: You don't need to have a `dist-server` folder.  I used Angular Universal with that project so that's why that folder is there.  All you need to do is run `ng build --prod` - no need to use yarn.  The important thing is to upload the already compiled dist folder to AWS Elastic Beanstalk